# Help me show that there exists an $x\in (\pi/2,\pi)$ such that $\sin x=\frac{x}{2}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

**Question**

Show that there exists an $x\in (\pi/2,\pi)$  such that $\sin x=\frac{x}{2}$

---

**My Solution**

The way I did it is:

$$\sin x=\frac{x}{2}$$
$$x=2\sin x$$

Using Taylor Series

$$x=2\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\cdots\right)$$

$$x=2x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\cdots$$

$$x< 2x - \frac{x^3}{3}$$

$$\implies 3x-x^3>0$$

Critical points are $x=0,x=\sqrt{3},x=-\sqrt{3}$

So this implies that

$$x\ge \sqrt{3}$$

Which is **True** because we are supposed to show that $x>\frac{\pi}{2}$

**Now, How do I show that it is also less than** $\pi$

This is where I face the problem, I can't find an equation to show that it is less than $\pi$ to complete the proof.

Comment: Hint:  let $g(x)=sin(x)-\frac x2$.  What is $g(\frac {\pi}2)$? What is $g(\pi)$?

Comment: @lulu You should turn that into an answer!

Comment: @lulu OH I see. Didn't see this ;) thanks alot :) Yes add this hint as an answer so that I can accept :)

Comment: Just posted a (slightly) expanded version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sketched in the comments:  This follows from the Intermediate Value Theorem applied to the function $$g(x)=sin(x)-\frac x2$$

Indeed, $g(\frac {\pi}2)=1 - \frac {\pi}4>0$  while $g(\pi)=-\frac {\pi}2<0$.